Is there a difference in casting a string to date using date() vs ::date vs date 'column' vs CAST(column AS DATE) in Postgresql
As far as I know there are the following 4 ways to cast a string to date in postgres:
SELECT '2024-04-03'::date AS colon_casting
    , date('2024-04-03') AS function_casting
    , date '2024-04-03' AS type_hinting_casting
    , CAST('2024-04-03' AS date) AS sql_compliant_casting

The question is: Is there a difference between them or are they alias to the same way to convert a string into date?

Is there a difference between them Of course. type_hinting_casting specifies literal datatype and does not perform any function processing whereas another 3 variants explicitly calls type-convertion functions. I.e. 3rd variant creates date-type value on the parsing/planning step whereas all other variants performs the convertion from the string-type value to the date-type value on the execution step.

@Akina You are right that the third variant is different because it only works with string literals, but all of there conversions would happen during query planning.

@LaurenzAlbe Deterministic constant expression is evaluated in PostgreSQL during query execution planning unconditionally?

@Akina Yes, if the functions involved are immutable.
